# How to prevent XeLaTex from creating .log file

Tags: xetex, miktex

Each time I compile my `.tex` file by `XeLaTex` from `Miktex`, a `.log` file is always created.

My question is: How to prevent XeLaTex from creating .log file.

Comment: You can't.  The .log is hardwired in (Xe)TeX.  Why do you want to prevent a log from being created?

Comment: in my makefile, I delete all intermediate files, including the log file before starting any compile. Also have a clean target which does that also in case I just need to clean the folder. So you can do `make all` then `make clean` btw, it is not only a .log file that gets created. Many other files also.

Comment: The content of  log file is nearly each time blank even if someting is wrong during compile. So the log file is useless for me but annoy me.

Comment: @lyl The .log should not be blank.  It should at the very least contain the `This is XeTeX, Version ...` line.  If it's blank, something is wrong.  But either way, you can't prevent a log from being created.

Comment: All right. Thank you all. May be something is wrong with my Emacs but I don't know.

Comment: More like permissions, perhas? Your editor should be fine.